# Ranking visits by a timestamp in StandardSQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am building a log of user interactions with a website, so far I have a row per visit showing the referral channel and a timestamp:

[image]

I'd like to rank each `visit_ref` by the date, so that the most recent have the highest rank and the furthest away have the lowest rank, within the date range that I query.

Here is my code so far, with channel removed to make it easier to read:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime) AS stamp, 
customDimension.value AS UserID,
CONCAT(CAST(fullVisitorId AS STRING),CAST(visitId AS STRING)) AS visit_ref,
COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(CAST(fullVisitorId AS STRING),CAST(visitId AS STRING))) OVER (PARTITION BY customDimension.value) AS total_visits_in_cycle,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CONCAT(CAST(fullVisitorId AS STRING),CAST(visitId AS STRING)), TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime) ORDER BY TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime)) AS visitrank,
  COUNT(DISTINCT transaction.transactionid) AS orders

FROM `xxx.xxx.ga_sessions_20*` AS t
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t.customdimensions) AS customDimension
WHERE parse_date('%y%m%d', _table_suffix) between 
DATE_sub(current_date(), interval 3 day) and
DATE_sub(current_date(), interval 1 day)
AND customDimension.index = 2
GROUP BY 1,2,3, fullVisitorId, visitid, visitStartTime
ORDER BY UserID
LIMIT 500
```

In this example, by rank is always coming back as `1` as seen in the screenshot, how can I get a rank of the unique `visit_ref` by timestamp?

My desired output is below, where the `visitrank` shows `1` against the oldest visit and `3` against the newest, for this user:

```
2   2018-05-07 08:02:30.000 UTC 00008736-01f0-4e0e-8e3b-4dc398e5b6f8    74664051693279955771525680150   3   2   Email - CRM Campaigns   0    
3   2018-05-06 21:59:20.000 UTC 00008736-01f0-4e0e-8e3b-4dc398e5b6f8    74664051693279955771525643960   3   1   Email - CRM Campaigns   0    
4   2018-05-07 05:39:15.000 UTC 00008736-01f0-4e0e-8e3b-4dc398e5b6f8    74664051693279955771525671555   3   3   Email - CRM Campaigns   0
```

`RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CONCAT(CAST(fullVisitorId AS STRING),CAST(visitId AS STRING)), TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime) ORDER BY TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime)) AS visitrank,`

I am working with Google BigQuery StandardSQL.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify, I am working with BigQuery StandardSQL.

Comment: I can't figure out what you want the values to actually be.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'd like a rank that shows me, in a single value, which were the most recent visits and which were the oldest, so I can sequence them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partition window defines the subset of records that should be considered. By including `TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime)`, you're setting the partition to what is always 1 record (though there might be more in your actual data on occasion) and you only ever see a rank of 1.

Also it isn't clear to me why you need to do the concat/casting in the partition definition, though perhaps there's some significant transformation occurring during this cast. I would use this:

```
rank() over (partition by fullVisitorId order by timestamp_seconds(visitStartTime) desc)
```

Comment: Thanks, when I run this code I am still getting a `1` for every row, any idea why this would be?

Comment: You don't have a visitId in your example output (but it looks like it's in the table). Is it unique to the visit? If so, i'll update the answer.

Comment: It is in the table, but I user the concatenation to get a *completely* unique session ID, so would prefer to use this in the rank too if I can.

Comment: If the concatenation produces a unique record and you partition by that record, you'll always get a visitRank of 1--this is what I'm trying to say in the answer. You can certainly generate this unique column _outside_ the partition definition. But inside it, but you need to keep it to the size of the rows you want ranked. From the question, that sounds like the visitor ID.

Comment: Aha, I understand now! Perhaps rank is not the best approach in this case if I want to rank timestamps that are unique?

Comment: I think you're probably just dealing with the English for "rank timestamps". When you rank timestamps, you always rank them _for_ something. I think that `rank()` is fine here, though perhaps you want `row_number()`.